# sed cutting first match in expression

Tags: bash, sed

from the original file I have this

```
"Reserved DB Instances","State","Start Time"
"alpha-db-dev-26aug2021","active","2021-08-26T06:29:11.121000+00:00"
"beta-db-dev-26aug2021","active","2021-08-26T09:30:49.669000+00:00"
"charlie-db-dev-8dec2021","active","2021-12-08T06:36:26.307000+00:00"
```

the goal is to remove all of the numbers after T, without eliminating the word "Time"

running the command `sed -e s/[0-9]T.*//g csvtest2.csv`
gives me this output

```
"Reserved DB Instances","State","Start Time"
"alpha-db-dev-26aug2021","active","2021-08-2
"beta-db-dev-26aug2021","active","2021-08-2
"charlie-db-dev-8dec2021","active","2021-12-0
```

The problem here is that the last number of the dates gets cut off.

The expcted output should be like this:

```
"Reserved DB Instances","State","Start Time"
"alpha-db-dev-26aug2021","active","2021-08-26"
"beta-db-dev-26aug2021","active","2021-08-26"
"charlie-db-dev-8dec2021","active","2021-12-08"
```

I cannot use `sed -e s/T.*//g csvtest2.csv` as this would result in a format like this despite the date being correct it cut off the word "Time"

```
"Reserved DB Instances","State","Start 
"alpha-db-dev-26aug2021","active","2021-08-26
"beta-db-dev-26aug2021","active","2021-08-26
"charlie-db-dev-8dec2021","active","2021-12-08
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```bash
sed '2,$ s/T[0-9][^"]*//' file

"Reserved DB Instances","State","Start Time"
"alpha-db-dev-26aug2021","active","2021-08-26"
"beta-db-dev-26aug2021","active","2021-08-26"
"charlie-db-dev-8dec2021","active","2021-12-08"
```

**Breakup:**

- `2,$`: Do this from line no. 2 to last line
- `s/T[0-9][^"]*//`: Substitute command that matches letter `T` followed by a digit and everything that is not `"` thus stopping before last `"`. This is replaced with just an empty string.

Comment: This seems like a cleaner implementation than the one I came up with as an answer. Thank you so much! Marking this as the correct answer as this was better and I appreciate the breakup!

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/T[0-9:.+]+//' input_file
"Reserved DB Instances","State","Start Time"
"alpha-db-dev-26aug2021","active","2021-08-26"
"beta-db-dev-26aug2021","active","2021-08-26"
"charlie-db-dev-8dec2021","active","2021-12-08"
```

Answer (score 1):

Was able to get it after fiddling around and changing my logic using `sed -e s/T[0-9].*/\"/g`

This produced the expected result

```
"Reserved DB Instances","State","Start Time"
"alpha-db-dev-26aug2021","active","2021-08-26"
"beta-db-dev-26aug2021","active","2021-08-26"
"charlie-db-dev-8dec2021","active","2021-12-08"
```

Thank you so much for everyone's input!